# How to locate any number, divide by 16 ;px to rem conversion

Tags: jquery, regex

I'm converting a large set of CSS pages from px to rem.
Rather than do 4000 of these by hand, I'm trying to build a jquery page to

1) locate all the occurrences of 'px' in the css pages                  (done)
2) then insert a space between the px and the number it modifies        (done)
3) locate all the resulting, free-standing numbers (0 thru 9999)        need help
4) divide those numbers by 16 (to obtain the floating pt numbers(4))    need help
5) convert the 'px' to 'rem'                                            (done)
6) then attach the new rem to the number after dividing it              (done)

I've done the easy parts 1, 2, 5 and 6, but I need help on the important 
stuff. The working page simply uses php includes to echo all of the css pages into
one page:

```
<?php include('CSS/screen/1_3.css');?>
<?php include('CSS/screen/2.css');?> etc and they display as expected:

@charset "utf-8"; /* CSS Document */ 
#apDiv1 { position: absolute; left: 3px; z-index: 1; width: 44px; top: 24%;} 
#apDiv2 { position: absolute; right: 300px z-index: 2; width: 49px; top: 24px; } 
a:link {text-decoration: none; font-size: 1.125rem;}
```

etc.

For steps 1 & 2, I use this below from Stack user j08691 on #25109275

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#separate").click(function() {
$("#container").contents().each(function () {
 if (this.nodeType === 3) this.nodeValue = $.trim($(this).text()).replace(/px/g, " px")
 if (this.nodeType === 1) $(this).html( $(this).html().replace(/px/g, " px") )
})
});
 });
```

That locates and separates the px and I reattach it as rem in Steps 5 & 6.
Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fhqc8362/

My problem is, I've only a nodding acquaintance with regex and I can't write the 2 steps 
to locate all the numbers and then divide them by 16.

I've looked at some of Stack's sass answers and they aren't really doing what I'm trying to do. I'm thinking something like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#locate").click(function() {
$("#container").contains then a regex to identify the numbers
});
 });
```

but even then I don't yet know how to use 'each' to divide them in the returned array

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#divide").click(function() {
$("#container").contains then a regex to identify the numbers
});
 });
```

Can someone point me in the right direction for the regex and how to divide it up?

Thank you. Your help is appreciated and up voted.

Comment: I'm not sure why you're doing this with jQuery on the "calculated" css, you should search for px in the css files using a text editor with search and replace capabilities (possibly, with regexp support for ease of use), like Notepad++ on Windows.

Comment: Yes, I did half of them already in a text editor, but the remaining are too numerous and not similar enough to productively find them in groups.

Comment: What about [replace with callback function](http://jsfiddle.net/a33rnehu/), not sure if that's what you need :)

Comment: @Jonny5  That may be a start, let me mess around with it for a bit. Is there a 'find any number' in jquery?

Answer (score 2):

Ok, apart from my obsarvation that this should be done on the offline css files instead of the calculated online css values, you should know that in using regular expression the best way is to do all things and all modifications in a single pass, if possible.

So, your code should become this:

```
if (this.nodeType === 3) this.nodeValue = $.trim($(this).text()).replace( /(\d*)px/g, function(match, p1) { 
    int num = parseInt(p1);

    //do all your conversions on num

    return num+"em";
});
```

Note that I'm matching (\d*) that means that p1 get to store all the consecutive digits immediately followed by 'px'. The regular expression pattern matching '()' does the separating from the px part for me. Then you convert the string to number (can fail, so you'd better test num is not NaN) and modify it to your heart's content before returning it as a replacement for the matched text.

Now, I've not tested this code and it has been some time since I last used regexp in javascript, so the syntax could be off.

Still, the idea is this: once you get hold of the snippet that you want modified, you don't relinquish it until you're done with it. 
Sometimes that's not possible, since you have to insert some global parameter that you still don't know when you do the match, but it's not the case here.

Comment: Thanks A. Rama. I'll plug it in and work with it to see if I can get it. Thanks especially for the additional explanation.

Comment: Forgot some good sources of info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace